Creating a Rectangular curve shape with border
I am trying to create a exact rectangle curve shape [brown color] section with border as like in the below image


I able to create exact shape with mask css property but unable to add the border top to the div attached the code for the same and attached the current image below


.item-meta-container {
    --c: 50px;
    mask: radial-gradient(100% var(--c) at top, #0000 calc(100% - 1px), #000);
    background: #35090A;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 11px;
    border: 1px solid #474747;
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
  }
<div class="item-meta-container"></div>



help me with adding the border top to the mask element as like in above image
current image with above css


you will have a one-color background?

@TemaniAfif Yes only one color background

Use a similar gradient configuration with background to create the top border


.item-meta-container {
  --c: 60px;                        /* adjust the -1px to control the thickness */
  mask:       radial-gradient(70% var(--c) at 50% -1px, #0000  calc(100% - 2px),#000);
  background: radial-gradient(70% var(--c) at 50% 0   , yellow calc(100% - 2px),#35090A);
  border-radius: 11px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}

body {
  background: #333
}
<div class="item-meta-container"></div>




This Works fine for my design, Thanks a lot.

If you want to add a border (like with border-top), using the mask css attribute will simply "cut-off" the visible shape, and neither outline nor border will be displayed. (depends of the mask's shape of course)
The best way to do this would be to make this curved shape in a svg (and with the border/outline you're looking for), and put it as a background image (much more flexible way), or by just playing with radial-background like proposed above.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
